# 'Join Geometry' node does not work with uv maps

Tags: modeling, uv, geometry-nodes

I'm just playing around with the new geometry nodes and noticed that whenever I use 'Join Geometry' it kills the uv map. (No Uvmap present anymore after appliying the modifier.) If I use 'Boolean' on union, it works fine. This has to be a known bug, right ? Couldn't find it though ....

Anyone knows what's going on ?

Comment: This bug has been report in https://developer.blender.org/T85962

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround (as long as you do not use `Realize Instances`):

If you enable the *As Instance* option in the `Object Info` node, your *UVMap* will be applied correctly.

[image]